# Cannot get correct output from program redirected via pipe C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, createprocess

I would like to achieve a result, so that the output of the program goes splitted to the deque structure.

To describe to problem: I am dealong with with the redirecting the output of the program created with CreateProcess. I need to read the output of program and process it line by line. The program itself provides the output in the convenient form, but the output which I receive via unnamed pipe is delivered slower (with smaller frequency) they appear in the portions and in such a way that the last line is somewhere cut in half. The next portion of the stream from the pipe will match and finish the line, but it will make some problems with the construction of the program.

What be a source of this discrepancy betweenn the cout from the program and the output redirected throught the pipe?

EDIT: According to the proposition by 
[user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) I've tried to use the stringstream and getline, but it seems that the lines are still cut in half even though the direct cout from the program without redirection to pipe does not have this problem. This leads to the issue, that the lines are splitted in the different elements of the queue (please look at the code below).

[Sample from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIsDc.png)

The method ReadFromPipe is run in the loop.

```
void ProcessManagement::ReadFromPipe(void)

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT

{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    std::deque<std::deque<std::string>> elems;

while (ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
{
    /* add terminating zero */
    buffer[dwRead] = '\0';
    std::stringstream streamBuffer;
    streamBuffer << buffer;
    BufferToQueue(streamBuffer, ' ', elems);

    // Print deque
    for (std::deque <std::string> a : elems)
    {
        for (std::string b : a)
            std::cout << b;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    }
}
```

And the method BufferToQueue.

```
void ProcessManagement::BufferToQueue(std::stringstream &streamBuffer, char delim, std::deque<std::deque<std::string>> &elems) {
    std::string line;
    std::string word;
    std::deque<string> row;

 // Splitting the stringstream into queue of queue (does not work properly)
    while (std::getline(streamBuffer, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (std::getline(iss, word, delim))
            row.push_back(word);
    elems.push_back(row);
    row.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like you forgot to flush.

Comment: Off topic: Have you considered writing the pipe output into a `std::stringstream` and then reading using `std::getline` on the stream?

Comment: Question eddited according to the suggestion. I did not try more with the flush as the sending the text on the screen is not strictly neccessary for the application to work properly, it was only a way for the beginning to check how to program behaves. I am concerned with the thing, that the strings are not put in the queue correctly after being split with getline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Captain Obvlious's comment regarding flush:

The problem you are facing is because the WriteToPipe function does not flush at end of line. You can fix this in the reader by ensuring that you append to the previous string if the the previous `ReadFromPipe` call did not have a `newline` as the last character.

Modified functions:

```cpp
bool ProcessManagement::BufferToQueue(std::stringstream &streamBuffer, char     delim, std::deque<std::deque<std::string>> &elems)
{
    std::string line;
    std::string word;
    std::deque<string> row;

    bool is_unflushed_line = streamBuffer.str().back() != '\n';

    // Splitting the stringstream into queue of queue (does not work properly)
    while (std::getline(streamBuffer, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (std::getline(iss, word, delim)) {
            row.push_back(word);
        }
        elems.push_back(row);
        row.clear();
    }
    return is_unflushed_line;
}

void ProcessManagement::ReadFromPipe(void)
// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    std::deque<std::deque<std::string>> elems;

    while (ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
    {
        /* add terminating zero */
        buffer[dwRead] = '\0';
        std::stringstream streamBuffer;
        streamBuffer << buffer;
        bool is_unflushed_line = BufferToQueue(streamBuffer, ' ', elems);

        for(auto idx = 0; idx != elems.size(); ++idx)
        {
            for (std::string const& b : elems[idx])
                std::cout << b;
            if(idx == elems.size() - 1 && is_unflushed_line)
                break;// don't print a newline if input did not end with a newline
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It got me the direction, the problem is, that not properly reproduced string appears not only on the end of the stringstream, may it be the problem with the split function? I was also using it in the past, without any problems though.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible that the stringstream recieves any "garbage" from the pipe? It seems that the split does not work correctly not only at the end of the stringstream (checked it with "if (idx == elems.size() - 1) std::cout << "stream end"; ") but also in other places. It is getting very nasty... Maybe I should try to get the output from the program in the different way that with a unnamed pipe with CreateProcess()? Any suggestions?

Comment: What I have also done is that I was checking the 2nd element in the created deque and in some cases a incorrect string is being placed (i.e. the line was split somewhere else and the end of the line was pushed in the new row). Is it still problem with flushing? Because as I mentioned it occurs not only at the end of stringstream.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @indeterminately sequenced was correct, thank you for your help. The problem was, that the buffer to which the pipe was copied was too small and it was deviding it to the seperate ones.

The complete solution based on the help of @indeterminately sequenced to push the output to queue structure, maybe it will help someone. The only problem is that the opened program is never closed, the TerminateProcess function has to be used somewhere.

```
void ProcessManagement::CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) };

    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;   //Pipe handles are inherited by child process.
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe to get results from child's stdout.
    if (!CreatePipe(&hPipeRead, &hPipeWrite, &saAttr, 0))
        return;

    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = hPipeWrite;
    si.hStdError = hPipeWrite;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;       // Prevents cmd window from flashing. Requires STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW in dwFlags.

    std::string command_temp = (" -i \"LAN 3\"");
    LPSTR st = const_cast<char *>(command_temp.c_str());

    BOOL fSuccess = CreateProcessA(program_path.c_str(), st, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        CloseHandle(hPipeWrite);
        CloseHandle(hPipeRead);
        return ;
    }

    /* Needs to be used somewhere
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess,exitCode);
    CloseHandle(hPipeWrite);
    CloseHandle(hPipeRead);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);*/
}

void ProcessManagement::ReadFromPipe(void)
// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
{
    std::deque<std::deque<std::string>> elems;

    // Give some timeslice (50ms), so we won't waste 100% cpu.
    bProcessEnded = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 50) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;

    // Even if process exited - we continue reading, if there is some data available over pipe.
    for (;;)
    {
        char buf[8192];
        DWORD dwRead = 0;
        DWORD dwAvail = 0;

        if (!::PeekNamedPipe(hPipeRead, NULL, 0, NULL, &dwAvail, NULL))
            break;

        if (!dwAvail) // no data available, return
            break;
        if (!::ReadFile(hPipeRead, buf, min(sizeof(buf)-1, dwAvail), &dwRead, NULL) || !dwRead)
            // error, the child process might ended
            break;
        buf[dwRead] = '\0';
        std::stringstream streamBuffer;
        streamBuffer << unflushed_line << buf; // add to buffer also last unflashed line
        unflushed_line = BufferToQueue(streamBuffer, ' ', elems);

        for (auto idx = 0; idx != elems.size(); ++idx)
        {
            for (std::string const& b : elems[idx])
                std::cout << b;

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    }
}

std::string ProcessManagement::BufferToQueue(std::stringstream &streamBuffer, char delim, std::deque<std::deque<std::string>> &elems) {
    std::string line;
    std::string word;
    std::deque<string> row;

    bool is_unflushed_line = streamBuffer.str().back() != '\n';

    // Splitting the stringstream into queue of queue (does not work properly)
    while (std::getline(streamBuffer, line, '\n'))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (std::getline(iss, word, delim)) {
            row.push_back(word);
        }
        elems.push_back(row);
        row.clear();
    }

    if (is_unflushed_line)
    {
        elems.pop_back(); // pop not fully flushed line
    }
    else line.clear(); // if the line was fully flushed return empty string

    return line; // to add to buffer for next push to queue if the last was not flushed at the end

}
```

Comment: Anyway, does anyway have an idea how to make this flushing a bit faster so that it will not wait untill it is full (because I guess that is what is happening)? Changing the pipe size in CreatePipe function does not make any change, so maybe my reasoning is wrong. The function [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx) does not help here either.